# recording a vector of the received power for each vehicle

Tags: omnet++

I'm working on a project with veins. I would like to record for each vehicle the received power.
I did the following:
I defined in the TraciDemo11p.h

```
cOutVector received_power;
```

in the TraciDemo11p.c I added the following headers

```
#include "veins/base/phyLayer/PhyToMacControlInfo.h"
#include "veins/modules/phy/DeciderResult80211.h"
```

and i added a small code to the function onData(WaveShortMesage *msg)

```
void TraCIDemo11p::onData(WaveShortMessage* wsm) {
findHost()->getDisplayString().updateWith("r=16,green");
annotations->scheduleErase(1, annotations->drawLine(wsm->getSenderPos(), mobility->getPositionAt(simTime()), "blue"));
power= (DeciderResult80211*)((PhyToMacControlInfo*)wsm->getControlInfo())->getDeciderResult()->getRecvPower_dBm() ;
received_power.record(power);
if (mobility->getRoadId()[0] != ':') traciVehicle->changeRoute(wsm->getWsmData(), 9999);
if (!sentMessage) sendMessage(wsm->getWsmData());
```

}

after running simulation I don't find the vector received_power in the results, please can somebody help me.
thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set a name of output vector. Add the line:

```
received_power.setName("Received power");
```

in `initialize()`.

Answer (score 0):

hello I found the solution, Just i had to build the project each time now it works thank you anyway.